# ContentControl WPF does not display Content

Tags: c#, wpf, metafile

I've convertet the Project from https://silverlightcontrib.codeplex.com/  to WPF (github https://github.com/jogibear9988/silverlightcontrib) to get EMF/WMF metafile support in WPF.

Now my Probjem is, the EMF Class uses a ContentControl for displaying it's Content. The Content is also set, but nothing is displayed. If I check it in WPF-Inspector, I see that the EMF Control has it's Content listed in the "Logical-Tree" but not in the Visual! Can anyone help me out with this?

The current state of the Fork is Online (if anyone will look at the Code!)

If I look in snoop everything seems alright:

[image]

You see, the Content Presenter has a Content set and Filled, but it does not get into the Visual Tree...

Here is the Logical Tree from WPF Inspector:
[image]

And here the Visual:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with Silverlight, but in WPF when you override `MeasureOverride(...)` and `ArrangeOverride(...)` you have to measure and arrange the contol's children so they can measure and arrange their children and so on.
In your case, you have to include calls to `base.MeasureOverride(...)` and `base.ArrangeOverride(...)` in the `Emf` class that inherits from `ContentControl`.

Answer (score 1):

The two most likely issues are that your `ContentControl` is using a `ControlTemplate` that has no `ContentPresenter` (on one that is specifically using something other than the default `Content` property) or that it is using an empty `DataTemplate` as its `ContentTemplate`. You should be able to check either of these by inspecting at runtime.

Comment: I'm using the Default Template of ContentControl, and no Datatemplate, so I think it should work?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't quite figured this out, but it's something to do with the sizing. In Snoop it is showing a RenderSize of 0,0 and in inspector the actual height/width is also showing as 0 - you can see the red highlight inspector draws around the element is a small dot rather than a rectangle. I am guessing there's some Silverlight specific behaviour in the EMF control that doesn't port directly to WPF.

Comment: I've now tried to set the with & height of the ContentPresenter, but the Content is still not rendered...